# Finding the Table and Column Based on a Known Value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've inherited a rather large SQL Server 2012 database -- about 2TB, tens of millions of rows in some tables, and about 350 different tables. I have basically no references nor documentation.

There's a type of file I need to generate which contains information stored somewhere in this database. I have one example of such file, so I have concrete values, but no idea as to where each of its fields came from.

For instance, I have an entry in the output file labeled UUID which has a value of `a03dc6109c6f53ce93203f1b85c7d31d`. After much uncomfortable digging, I found a column in one of the tables called "custom_value_1" with the value `a03dc610-9c6f-53c-e932-03f1b85c7d31d`, which I'm pretty sure semantically corresponds to what I wanted. But I have many such values to find, and it seems pretty unlikely that I'll be able to stumble across them all.

So how can I search all the columns across all the tables in a database for a particular value? I'd love to be able to say something like:

```
SELECT * FROM * WHERE * = 'HB194';
```

and have it search every column (skipping those of inapplicable types; no timestamps if I'm searching for a string) of every table for the value 'HB194'. Obviously something more complex will need to be employed, but I don't think I have the time (nor the fortitude) to manually craft a specific select query for each of the 350 tables for each of the dozen or so values I'm looking for.

Comment: That value you show in the question is typically referred to as a GUID, or Globally Unique Identifier (`uniqueidentifier` in SQL Server parlance).  Are all the values you looking for a GUID?

Comment: @MaxVernon No, most of them are likely VARCHAR, like 'HB194' or 'Immediately'.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That looks promising. I'm running it for a known value now while I try to understand more than generally how it works, but it's got the essence of what I want to do -- search every string column on every table for a particular value. I don't think such brute-forcing could be done faster.

Comment: You can even limit it to string columns that are large enough to actually contain your value.

Comment: While it's still technically running, I think I've already found one of the fields that I want and some more tables of interest besides. @AaronBertrand -- think you could type up (or even copy/paste) your solution into an answer here so it's obvious for future string-searchers. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my post about this issue [here (see #1)](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/grouped-concatenation-use-cases):

```
DECLARE 
  @Search1 NVARCHAR(4000) = N'%a03dc6109c6f53ce93203f1b85c7d31d%',
  @Search2 NVARCHAR(4000) = N'%a03dc610-9c6f-53c-e932-03f1b85c7d31d%',
  @s NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

;WITH t AS (
    SELECT t.[object_id], [table] = t.name, [schema] = s.name
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns
          WHERE [object_id] = t.[object_id]
          AND (system_type_id IN (35,99) -- text, ntext
          OR (system_type_id IN (167,175,231,239) -- (n)(var)(char)
            AND (max_length = -1 OR max_length >=32) -- max or >= LEN(@Search1)
             )))
)
SELECT @s = @s + N'SELECT N''' 
    + REPLACE([schema],'''','''''') + '.' 
    + REPLACE([table], '''','''''') + ''',* 
 FROM ' + QUOTENAME([schema]) + '.' + QUOTENAME([table]) + '
 WHERE ' + STUFF((SELECT '
 OR ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' LIKE ' + CASE 
      WHEN system_type_id IN (99,231,239) 
      THEN 'N' ELSE '' END
      + '''' + @Search1 + '''' -- run again with @Search2
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE [object_id] = t.[object_id]
    AND system_type_id IN (35,99,167,175,231,239)
    ORDER BY name
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,6,'') + ';

'
FROM t;

PRINT @s;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @s;
```

Comment: You're awesome. Is it possible to filter out empty tables from the output?

Comment: @Shahriar Sure, just change to `where exists (…) and t.[object_id] in (select [object_id] from sys.partitions where index_id in (0,1) and [rows] > 0)`.

Comment: which line should I change?

Comment: @Shahriar the line that says `WHERE EXISTS` … there’s only one.

Comment: thank you but it still returns empty tables. By filtering empty tables out, I meant the tables in results, not the empty tables in db.

Comment: @Shahriar I think we have different definitions for “empty” - could you explain what you mean in a different way, without using the word “empty”?

Comment: An image is worth a thousand words: https://ibb.co/f1P9spT

Comment: When we execute the query, all of the tables are present in the output. Some of them include our search value, and some of them don't. I want to only see the tables where the search value is in one of the columns.

Comment: @Shahriar Do you mean all queries produce a row that says `SELECT FROM table WHERE column LIKE @param`? Yes, that's the point. This produces the queries you then need to run against each table. The results from _those_ queries will only contain rows where the string matches - which, for some tables, will be 0. Remember to uncomment the `EXEC` line. The `PRINT` will of course show _all_ the tables because it hasn't been executed yet. If you don't want results for "empty" tables, change the logic to just include each column, and dump to a #temp table. Too much for comments on a 10-year old post.